# How to compare two nano time values? [javadoc confusion]

Tags: java, time, comparison, integer-overflow

I have read the javadoc for `System.nanoTime()` and it all seems clear. Until I reached the final paragraph:

> To compare two nanoTime values
>
> `long t0 = System.nanoTime();`
>
> `...`
>
> `long t1 = System.nanoTime();`
>
> one should use t1 - t0 < 0, not t1 < t0, because of the possibility of numerical overflow.

There are two things that are unclear to me:

1. Why would one check if `t1 < t0` if `t1` was taken after `t0`? My understanding is that nano time is always increasing. So, I would rather check `t1 > t0`.
2. Let's suppose that's a typo, and they meant the correct check is `t1 - t0 > 0`. I still don't get it why that is the correct way of checking and not `t1 > t0`. They mention the numerical overflow and I don't quite get what they mean. Regarding the numerical overflow, here's what is mentioned:

> Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (2^63 nanoseconds) will not correctly compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.

OK, so since the nano time is stored as a long value, it will eventually overflow in 292 years. And what happens next? Does it start from the beginning, i.e. the lowest negative value -2^63? Or does it stop measuring and returns (2^63 - 1) always?

Comment: an overflow for a numeric value is allways the same. for example`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: this is also only a workaround... after 584 years even `t1-t0<0` won't work anymore ;)

Comment: @ferrybig, that's not true. As pointed out by the Javadoc, nano time uses a fixed origin time that is not related to the system time and won't change until JVM is terminated. The one that changes with the system clock is System.currentTimeMillis() though. Nano time will return an "earlier" time only when there's a numerical overflow which has been explained in most of the answers here.

Answer (score 10):

You are right, the parts of the documentation that you quoted seem to be a bit confused.

However, the part of the documentation that counts is this:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some **fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative)**. The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.

(emphasis added by me.)

What this means is that you do not have any guarantees that your code will not happen to be running at the time that the yielded long value will happen to flip from positive to negative.

There is nothing that guarantees that this will happen in 300 years from now, it may happen today.

Currently, my JVM returns some number like 3496793269188, but it could, if it wanted to, be returning some number very close to 9223372036854775807, (which is `Long.MAX_VALUE`,) which would make a flip from positive to negative imminent.

So, you should take all necessary precautions.

Comment: `Long.compare(t0, t1)` doesn't do anything about the overflow, though.

Comment: @user2357112 O_O you are right, I thought it did, and it turns out that it doesn't, and come to think of it now, it couldn't. Duh! I don't know why I felt compelled to mention it.  I will remove it right now.

Comment: This answer along with others explaining the overflow arithmetics helped me and it is all clear now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, `javadoc` says truth. Consider such example:

```
        long t0 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long t1 = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        System.out.println(t1 < t0);
        System.out.println(t1 - t0 < 0);
```

It will give

```
true
false
```

while mathematically both expressions are true. But in our case we know, that negative value of `time` means, that it is overflowed, hence it should be really *greater* then positive number.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start from the end of your question. Yes in case value is greater than 2^63-1 the value will overflow. Common implementation of an overflow is that the least significant representable bits of the result are stored; value will **wrap** (you can see at the bottom of my post about overflow for reference)

Sequence is like: `2^63-2, 2^63-1, -2^63, -(2^63-1) ...`

Now looking back at Javadoc I agree that the explanation about using comparison is confusing and that naturally we would try to compare `t1 > t0` to validate if `t1` happened after `t0`. *You are partially right. Though I don't think it is a typo but it is not explained correctly*. I think it should say:

> For two values `t0` and `t1` (where t1 is captured after t0), you should not use `t1 < t0` (to check for `false`) but rather `t1 - t0 < 0`, similarly you should not use `t1 > t0` (to check for `true`) but rather `t1 - t0 > 0`

Or to formalise it:

> For two 'nano' values `t0` and `t1`, where `t1` is captured after `t0` following stands: **`(t1 - t0 > 0) == true`** as long as the period between `t1` and `t0` is <= 2^63 ns.

*Why*? Because even when `t1` overflows (so it is negative), the result `t1 - t0` will also be negative **but, it will be less than -2^64 and  it will 'overflow back' to positive value!** .

This stands as long as the condition about the distance between `t0` and `t1` is met! In case the distance is larger than 2^64 e.g: for `t0 = 1; t1 = -(2^64-2)`, subtraction result would be: `t1 - t0 = -(2^64-1)` so the specified condition (`t1 - t0 > 0`) will give incorrect result.

Right?:)

### On overflow

For the sake of explanation lats assume a type that is stored using 8 bits (instead of 64 used by long), so binary to decimal representation is:

```
0000 0000 => 0
0000 0001 => 1 (2^0)
0000 0010 => 2 (2^1 + 2^0)
...
1111 1111 => 255 (2^7 + 2^6 + ... + 2^1)
```

now next number is naturally when you would increment by 1.
adding 1 to binary 1111 1111 will produce 1 0000 0000

`(1) 0000 0000 => -256 !!!` typically the overflown bit on a position 8 will represent a (negative-weight) sign bit

```
first following value is adding 1 to most-right position 
(1) 0000 0001 => -256 + 2^0 = -255
(1) 0000 0010 => -256 + 2^1 = -254
(1) 0000 0011 => -256 + 2^1 + 2^1 = -253
...
```

you get the picture

The origin of this is in the underlying hardware registry implementation which relies on binary values.
You can read more detailed explanation for instance here: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-2/binary-overflow/

Answer (score 2):

When t1 is take after t0 (t1 < t0 = false in real word) and there is an owerflow for t1 (not t0). t1 is negative and t0 positive is this case t1 - t0 < 0 give you the good result false because the binary operation '-' don't make mistake of owerflow and t1 < t0 will give you a wrong result : true

More basic a negative number if it read a unsigned number is bigger than a signed positive number : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations and